# Why is the Dataformatstring property not being applied to my grid?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datagridview, webforms

I am trying to apply the DataFormatString Property of a BoundField Column in my grid. I am doing this from the code behind as i want the DataFormatString value to be configurable.

I have applied it on some grids in other pages of my application where it has worked.

But i am unable to find out the reason why it is not working for this grid in my page which is the same asp grid as that in other pages.

Here is my aspx

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewYearWiseData" runat="server" CellPadding="2" AllowSorting="false"
                                                    SkinID="GridviewSkin" ViewStateMode="Enabled" ShowHeader="True" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                                                    AllowPaging="false" Width="250px" Height="99%" GridLines="None"
                                                    ShowFooter="false" EmptyDataText="No Data Found."
                                                    ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" HeaderStyle-Height="30px" RowStyle-Height="25px" OnDataBound="GridViewYearWiseData_DataBound" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridViewYearWiseData_SelectedIndexChanged"
                                                    BorderStyle="None">

<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Duration" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonRange" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Duration") %>' CommandName="Select"> </asp:LinkButton>
     <input type="hidden" id="FromMonth" value='<%# Eval("FromMonth") %>' runat="server" />
     <input type="hidden" id="ToMonth" value='<%# Eval("ToMonth") %>' runat="server" />
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:BoundField DataField="value1" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" ItemStyle-Width="80px" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />

<asp:BoundField DataField="value2" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" ItemStyle-Width="80px" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
</Columns>
<HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
<PagerSettings FirstPageText="First" LastPageText="Last" Mode="NextPreviousFirstLast" NextPageText="Next" PageButtonCount="4" PreviousPageText="Previous" />
</asp:GridView>
```

And here is my databound event.

```
protected void GridViewYearWiseData_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var currentMethod = (new System.Diagnostics.StackFrame()).GetMethod().Name;
        log.Info(AppConstants.StrStart + currentMethod);
        try
        {

            GridRoundoffDecimal =Convert.ToInt32(resXResourceSet.GetString("GridMaxDecimals"));//Line of code to get from the database, the number of decimals to be displayed in the grid after the decimal point
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView grid = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView)sender;
            BoundField col1 = (BoundField)grid.Columns[1];
            BoundField col2 = (BoundField)grid.Columns[2];

            col1.DataFormatString = "{0:N" + GridRoundoffDecimal + "}";
            col2.DataFormatString = "{0:N" + GridRoundoffDecimal + "}";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), mLiquidateMain.GlobalConstants.script, mLiquidateMain.GlobalConstants.alertOf + GetErrorMessage(ex.Message) + "\");", true);
            log.Error(ex.Message, ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            log.Info(AppConstants.StrEnd + currentMethod);
        }
    }
```

This is my DataSource

[image: My DataSource]

Any thoughts on where i am going wrong?

Comment: I'd start with checking that value1 and value2 have numeric data type in bound source.

Comment: @Alex Yes , the values are of numeric types only. I have updated my question with the screen shot of my datasource.